# ExpressiveAnnotations: translate global _defaultErrorMessage in RequiredIfAttribute

Tags: c#, translation, expressiveannotations

I want to use inheritance for `AssertThatAttribute` and `RequiredIfAttribute` but is not possible because both classes are `sealed` classes

```
public sealed class RequiredIfAttribute : ExpressiveAttribute
public sealed class AssertThatAttribute : ExpressiveAttribute
```

Is any other possibility to translate global _`defaultErrorMessage`

For example:

```
private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "Assertion for {0} field is not satisfied by the following logic: {1}";
```

I would like to translate it globally for whole project. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: probably you already saw this https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations/issues/70 and the related pull request, the simpliest solution is fork and free the RequiredIfAttribute

Comment: Under the link provided above I've just added an example of`ExpressiveAttribute` inheritance (with a few additional steps required to wire it up).

Comment: make it as a comment that i can accept it

Comment: Just for info. Code works before, but after new version I can not use translation message any more. Now is always in english. Why? What has changed?